# What is Baltasar Gracián's original quote to "Some never arrive at being complete, somewhat is always awanting"?

Tags: quote-source, spanish-language, baltasar-gracian

Can anyone find the original quote from Baltasar Gracián in the Spanish he wrote this in?

> Some never arrive at being complete, somewhat is always awanting.

From *The art of worldy wisdom*.

Answer (score 3):

Some call it Aphorism #6 but in the [text I found](https://freeditorial.com/en/books/el-arte-de-la-prudencia), it is #5:

> 5. Nadie es perfecto: No nacemos perfectos, cada día nos desarrollamos en nuestra personalidad y en nuestra profesión. Esto se conoce por la pureza de nuestros gustos, por la claridad de nuestras ideas, por la madurez de nuestros juicios y por la firmeza de nuestra voluntad. **La persona completa –sabia en el hablar, prudente en sus actos- es admirada.**

Full quote in English:

> We are not born perfect: every day we develop in our personality and in our calling till we reach the highest point of our completed being, to the full round of our accomplishment, of our excellences. This is known by the purity of our taste, the clearness of our thought, the maturity of our judgment, and the firmness of our will. Some never arrive at being complete; somewhat is always awanting: other ripen late.